# How to validate object values in jsonschema?

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Suppose I have a json like this:

```
{"1": {"first_name": "a", "last_name": "b"},
 "2": {"first_name": "c", "last_name": "d"}}
```

As you can see, values have such schema:

```
{"type": "object",
 "properties": {
    "first_name": {"type": "string"},
    "last_name": {"type": "string"}
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": ["first_name", "last_name"]}
```

I want to know how can I define a schema which can validate the above json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `additionalProperties` takes a JSON Schema as it's value. (Yes, a boolean is a valid JSON Schema!)

Let's recap what the `additionalProperties` keyword does...

> The behavior of this keyword depends on the presence and annotation
> results of "properties" and "patternProperties" within the same schema
> object. Validation with "additionalProperties" applies only to the
> child values of instance names that do not appear in the annotation
> results of either "properties" or "patternProperties".
>
> For all such properties, validation succeeds if the child instance
> validates against the "additionalProperties" schema.

https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#additionalProperties

In simplest terms, if you don't use `properties` or `patternProperties` within the same schema object, the value schema of `additionalProperties` applies to ALL values of the applicable object in your instance.

As such, you only need to nest your existing schema as follows.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "additionalProperties": YOUR SCHEMA
}
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot.